# how to provide data source for sales order grid using ui component in magento2 frontend

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, data-provider, datasource

The grid basically should contain sales order basic details such as order number, order status along with it should contain number of invoiced items, number of shipped items, number of invoices along with invoice numbers.

I know how to create ui component, but getting data from other tables such as sales_order_item,invoice table seems difficult.
can anyone help me on this.
Let's say 1 order contain sku1 10 ,sku2 20,sku3 30 .
Shipped items ( sku1 3 + sku2 4 +sku3 6) = 13
Invoiced items ( sku1 6 + sku2 10 + sku3 10) = 26
cancelled items ( sku1 1 + sku2 6 + sku3 14 ) = 21

Also concern about performance, because for each order we need calculate and need to provide data to the grid.
Offcourse we will add current customer as one filter.
Also we need to list number of invoices for that order,let's say it contains 4 partial invoices ( 000234,000235,000236,000237)

do we need to create separate read model for using cqrs , message queues?
or any custom indexer is enough?
also user should be able to filter & search with order item name or category as well.
so do we need to add this information to elastic search index  to get better performance

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: What is the better way to display such complex grid?

Comment: you must show order with all status like this [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XtSC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XtSC.png) this grid show one order and order product all status quantity wise.

Comment: sum (shipped), sum(invoiced)  i need to show, not individually